# Filesystem and journal layout

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Is there any tools or some way in linux which can be used to view internals of filesystems ?

How to view the inode related structures and journal  ? and cached pages of files (pagecache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will of course depend on what filesystem you are using,

[e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) contains debugfs which will work with ext2, ext3 and ext4, and is used to manually view or modify internal structures of the file system

man page for debugfs is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs)